# How to remove the suffix of string in text file using shell script and sed?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a text file named file.txt with the following content.

```
customer 
#line1-customer
security-team
#line1-security
```

I want only want to remove the # of #line1 under customer inside this file using shell script

My script

```
#!/bin/bash
string1="#line1-customer"
prefix=#

cat file.text | while read LINE
do
  if [ "$LINE" == "$string1" ]; then
  sed -i 's/"$LINE"/"$LINE#"$prefix""/g' file.text
done
```

After executing, no error was found.
But i checked the file.txt and it was still the same (the # was not removed)

How can i achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to remove the first character of the line starting with the pattern contained in the variable `string1`.

If so, no need for bash script, a single sed script is enough:

```
string1="#line1"
sed -i "/^${string1}/s/.\(.*\)$/\1/" file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @oliv for your answer. The reason i want to use script because there are so many identical line in file.txt. And i have to filter first then remove the #. I updated a little bit more details in my question.

Comment: I changed a little bit in shell and it worked!. You saved my day, bro.